# What is the bloc pattern implementation for newbies in flutter?

Tags: flutter, stream, bloc, reactivex, rxdart

I am a new user of flutter.

When using a project with flutter I've always only used stateflue widgets or stateless widgets.

I recently learned about state management and I researched for it.

There were many methods or packages for state management.

I decided to try the bloc pattern among them.

After some research, I found out that there are several ways to do programming using the bloc pattern.

I have selected three or so.

- How to use the dart stream
- How to use the rxdart package
- How to use the flutter_bloc package

At first I was thinking of using flutter_bloc, but after reading the StackOverflow questions and answers ( [What are disadvantages of using flutter_bloc library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63145257/what-are-disadvantages-of-using-flutter-bloc-library) )

I fell into trouble.

To better understand the bloc pattern, I thought it might be better to implement it myself using rxdart or stream rather than flutter_bloc.

Which of the 3 methods above is recommended for flutter newbies?

Or is there any other recommended way?

Comment: BLoC was creating as a state management pattern by the Flutter team, however, they do not recommend it anymore either. [Provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) is recommended now and it is probably more beginner friendly.

Comment: A goog starting point is [this doc guide](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options#general-overview), especially the linked articles of **Didier Boelens**, one of which shows how to implement Bloc yourself without use external packages. These articles also explain well **InheritedWidget**, which is also the basis of **provider**. On provider it is also interesting the twitter account of its creator, https://twitter.com/remi_rousselet, which has recently also published a 'sister' version, [**riverpod**: "Provider, but different"](https://riverpod.dev/).

Comment: I am using flutter_bloc. Maybe I do not do it as intended, I often have "rich" blocs stretching over multiples screens etc. The scenario mentioned in that q&a, I could easily put the carousel etc into a single bloc and update accordingly to the different progress. Not sure, if someone would call my result spaghetti. However, I looked into Didier Boelens' and other patterns. Flutter_bloc is for me - as a beginner - the by far preferred solution with a very clear design. Have a look to the Firestore ToDo example on bloclibrary.